# Retrieving settings of Slicers in data-sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2013, slicers, vba

I'm not even sure if this is possible. But I'm using a quite massive datasheet controlled mostly by slicers. When I make an extract of this datasheet, I would like to have the settings of the slicers and date/time of extraction in a header (as an extra confirmation of correct setting of slicers, and ofcourse a point in time when the data was extracted).

Google didn't know the answer, and since my google-fu tends to be strong, i've come for advice here.

Is this even possible? Preferably doing it in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh found it.

Created a PublicFunction using below code and it'll show the selected slicer values.

```
Public Function GetSelectedSlicerItems(SlicerName As String) As String
Dim oSc As SlicerCache
Dim oSi As SlicerItem
Dim lCt As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.Volatile
Set oSc = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName)
If Not oSc Is Nothing Then
    For Each oSi In oSc.SlicerItems
        If oSi.Selected Then
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = GetSelectedSlicerItems & oSi.Name & ", "
            lCt = lCt + 1
        ElseIf oSi.HasData = False Then
            lCt = lCt + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) > 0 Then
        If lCt = oSc.SlicerItems.Count Then
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = "All"
        Else
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = Left(GetSelectedSlicerItems, Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) - 2)
        End If
    Else
        GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No items selected"
    End If
Else
    GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No slicer with name '" & SlicerName & "' was found"
End If
End Function
```